# Question about Fourier coefficients of a newform at primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

For $q:=e^{2\pi i z},$  let $f(z)=\sum_{n\ge 1}\lambda(n)n^{(k-1)/2}q^n$ be a normalized newform of type $(k,\chi)$  and level $N$. For any prime $p,$ we have
$$\lambda(p)=2\cos(\theta_p)\;\;\;\text{for some}\;\;\; \theta_p\in[0,\pi]$$

I wonder: Is $\theta_p\pmod{2\pi}$ take only finitely many values when $p$ run over primes number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, as this would contradict the [Sato-Tate conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sato%E2%80%93Tate_conjecture). For CM forms this conjecture is easier and has been long known, see e.g. [this MO entry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114062/sato-tate-conjecture-for-cm-modular-forms).

Comment: This is exactly right when the weight of the newform isn't $1$. A weight $1$ newform does indeed only have finitely many different possibilities for $\theta_{p}$.

Comment: @JeremyRouse, Thank you very much for pointing out this.